# Find a character in a data frame and change adjacent rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame with 250,000 rows and 35 columns. A simpler sample can be generated by the following code:

```
data.frame(a=letters[sample(10,26,replace = T)],b=letters[1:26],c=letters[26:1])
```

I want to search for every occurrence of a chosen character, let's say "h" and then change the cell containing "h" and 5 rows above "h" to NA.

Comment: I just edited your question back to the original version. The reason is people have already developed answers to your original questions. If you changed your questions, it makes all the answers look "wrong". I believe you can start a new question without changing this one. Also, if there are any answers posted here solved your original question, please consider to accept it so that others know this question has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful that the generated indexes do not include negative
values.  For example, if a 'h' is in row 3, then only rows 1, 2, and 3 need to
be set to NA.  `df[3 -0:4, ] <- NA` will no generate the needed result.

For this example, we will generate a data.frame `df1` and a second copy,
`df2`, to make it easy to compare the results.  Notice that in column 'a'
there is an 'h' in row 2.

```
set.seed(2)
df1 <- df2 <-
  data.frame(a = letters[sample(10,26,replace = T)],
             b = c(letters[1:25],NA),
             c = c(letters[25:1],NA))
df1
#    a    b    c
# 1  b    a    y
# 2  h    b    x
# 3  f    c    w
# 4  b    d    v
# 5  j    e    u
# 6  j    f    t
# 7  b    g    s
# 8  i    h    r
# 9  e    i    q
# 10 f    j    p
# 11 f    k    o
# 12 c    l    n
# 13 h    m    m
# 14 b    n    l
# 15 e    o    k
# 16 i    p    j
# 17 j    q    i
# 18 c    r    h
# 19 e    s    g
# 20 a    t    f
# 21 g    u    e
# 22 d    v    d
# 23 i    w    c
# 24 b    x    b
# 25 d    y    a
# 26 e <NA> <NA>
```

use `lapply` to find the row indexes within each column where an 'h' occurs

```
h_idx <- lapply(df1, function(x) which(x == "h"))
# $a
# [1]  2 13
# 
# $b
# [1] 8
# 
# $c
# [1] 18
```

using `lapply` again, we build the row indexes to set to `NA` in each of the
columns.  Notice that the `seq` call starts from a max of the index minus four
and 1, this will prevent negative or zero indexes being called.

```
na_idx <- lapply(h_idx,
                 function(x) {
                   lapply(x, function(xx) {seq(max(c(xx - 4, 1)), xx, by = 1) })
                 })
na_idx
# $a
# $a[[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $a[[2]]
# [1]  9 10 11 12 13
# 
# 
# $b
# $b[[1]]
# [1] 4 5 6 7 8
# 
# 
# $c
# $c[[1]]
# [1] 14 15 16 17 18
```

for each column, set the needed rows to NA

```
for(cl in seq_along(df2)) {
  for (rws in na_idx[[cl]]) {
    df2[rws, cl] <- NA
  }
}
```

The result

```
cbind(df1, df2)
#    a    b    c    a    b    c
# 1  b    a    y <NA>    a    y
# 2  h    b    x <NA>    b    x
# 3  f    c    w    f    c    w
# 4  b    d    v    b <NA>    v
# 5  j    e    u    j <NA>    u
# 6  j    f    t    j <NA>    t
# 7  b    g    s    b <NA>    s
# 8  i    h    r    i <NA>    r
# 9  e    i    q <NA>    i    q
# 10 f    j    p <NA>    j    p
# 11 f    k    o <NA>    k    o
# 12 c    l    n <NA>    l    n
# 13 h    m    m <NA>    m    m
# 14 b    n    l    b    n <NA>
# 15 e    o    k    e    o <NA>
# 16 i    p    j    i    p <NA>
# 17 j    q    i    j    q <NA>
# 18 c    r    h    c    r <NA>
# 19 e    s    g    e    s    g
# 20 a    t    f    a    t    f
# 21 g    u    e    g    u    e
# 22 d    v    d    d    v    d
# 23 i    w    c    i    w    c
# 24 b    x    b    b    x    b
# 25 d    y    a    d    y    a
# 26 e <NA> <NA>    e <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lapply` to identify the character and replace to `NA`, and also replace the previous 5 rows. Assuming that your data frame is `dt`. I created the `dt` as follows.

```
set.seed(155)

dt <- data.frame(a=letters[sample(10,26,replace = T)],b=letters[1:26],c=letters[26:1],
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(dt)
#   a b c
# 1 h a z
# 2 e b y
# 3 h c x
# 4 h d w
# 5 e e v
# 6 d f u
```

And then we can first replace all `h` to `NA`.

```
dt2 <- dt
dt2[dt2 == "h"] <- NA

# head(dt2)
#      a b c
# 1 <NA> a z
# 2    e b y
# 3 <NA> c x
# 4 <NA> d w
# 5    e e v
# 6    d f u
```

We can then replace all the previous 5 rows by `NA` as follows. `dt3` is the final output.

```
dt3 <- dt2
dt3[] <- lapply(dt3, function(x){
  index <- which(is.na(x))
  index2 <- lapply(index, function(x) x:(x - 5))
  index3 <- unique(unlist(index2))
  index4 <- index3[index3 > 0]
  x[index4] <- NA
  return(x)
})

dt3
#       a    b    c
# 1  <NA>    a    z
# 2  <NA>    b    y
# 3  <NA> <NA>    x
# 4  <NA> <NA>    w
# 5  <NA> <NA>    v
# 6  <NA> <NA>    u
# 7  <NA> <NA>    t
# 8     f <NA>    s
# 9     e    i    r
# 10    f    j    q
# 11    j    k    p
# 12    b    l    o
# 13    b    m    n
# 14    e    n <NA>
# 15    b    o <NA>
# 16    i    p <NA>
# 17    e    q <NA>
# 18    f    r <NA>
# 19    i    s <NA>
# 20    b    t    g
# 21    g    u    f
# 22    e    v    e
# 23    c    w    d
# 24    c    x    c
# 25    b    y    b
# 26    e    z    a
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the most elegant or simple way, but I think it answers your question.

```
set.seed(100)
df <-data.frame(a=letters[sample(10,26,replace = T)],b=letters[1:26],c=letters[26:1])

repNa <- function(col, char) {
    col[unique(unlist(sapply(which(col==char),
                             FUN=function(x) rep(ifelse(x>4,(x-4),1):x))
                      ))
        ] <- NA
    return(col)
}

df
as.data.frame(apply(df, MARGIN=2, function(x) repNa(x, "h")))
```

The `repNa` function is not very complex, the most important part is `unique(unlist(sapply(which(col==char),FUN=function(x) rep(ifelse(x>4,(x-4),1):x))))`, with which build a vector with the positions to replace in a certain column.

Input:

```
   a b c
1  d a z
2  c b y
3  f c x
4  a d w
5  e e v
6  e f u
7  i g t
8  d h s
9  f i r
10 b j q
11 g k p
12 i l o
13 c m n
14 d n m
15 h o l
16 g p k
17 c q j
18 d r i
19 d s h
20 g t g
21 f u f
22 h v e
23 f w d
24 h x c
25 e y b
26 b z a
```

Output:

```
      a    b    c
1     d    a    z
2     c    b    y
3     f    c    x
4     a <NA>    w
5     e <NA>    v
6     e <NA>    u
7     i <NA>    t
8     d <NA>    s
9     f    i    r
10    b    j    q
11 <NA>    k    p
12 <NA>    l    o
13 <NA>    m    n
14 <NA>    n    m
15 <NA>    o <NA>
16    g    p <NA>
17    c    q <NA>
18 <NA>    r <NA>
19 <NA>    s <NA>
20 <NA>    t    g
21 <NA>    u    f
22 <NA>    v    e
23 <NA>    w    d
24 <NA>    x    c
25    e    y    b
26    b    z    a
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct the following might work. I am not sure, if it will work for your large data frame.

```
df<-data.frame(a=letters[sample(10,26,replace = T)],b=letters[1:26],c=letters[26:1])
u<-df=='h'
v<-rbind(u[6:26,], matrix(nrow=5, ncol=3, FALSE))
df[u|v]=NA
```